# Excepción al introducir cualquier tipo de variable - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, matemáticas

Estoy tratando de escribir un programa que compare tres números y me haga una exponencial, debo hacerlo de la forma que me piden en la universidad, usando distintas clases y métodos, abajo tienen un *PDF* con detalles.

Tengo dos clases, la primera se llama `MyMath` y contiene lo siguiente:

```
package leandro;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyMath {
    public static int maximo(int a,int b) { //Cálculo del valor máximo entre dos variables.
        int max =0;
        if(a>b){
            max=a;
        }else{
            max=b;
        }
        return max;
    }
    public static String[] captura_datos(){ //Entrada de datos y salida de un string ordenado.
        Scanner tec= new Scanner(System.in);
        String a;
        System.out.println("Introduce tres números separados por un espacio: ");
        a=tec.nextLine();
        String vector[]=a.split(" ");
        tec.close();
        return vector;
    }
    public static double potencia( double base, int exponente){
        double potencia=Math.pow(base, exponente);
        return potencia;
    }

}
```

La segunda clase se llama `UsingMyMath` y contiene lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import leandro.MyMath;
public class UsingMyMath {
    public static void main(String[] args){ //Salida
        String[] numeros = MyMath.captura_datos();
        int a,b,c,max;
        int exponente=0;
        double base=0;
        a=Integer.parseInt(numeros[0]);
        b=Integer.parseInt(numeros[1]);
        c=Integer.parseInt(numeros[2]);
        a=MyMath.maximo(a, b);
        max=MyMath.maximo(a, c);
        System.out.println("El valor máximo es: "+max);
        System.out.println("Introduzca la base del número a elevar: ");
        Scanner teclado= new Scanner(System.in);
        base=teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Introduzca su exponente: ");
        exponente=teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.close();
        System.out.println("El resultado es: "+ MyMath.potencia(base, exponente));
    }
}
```

El problema reside en la parte de entrada de datos para el cálculo de la exponencial (Método `UsingMyMath`), ya que al añadir `base=teclado.nextDouble();` me salta un error en la consola de este tipo:

```
Introduce tres números separados por un espacio: 
10 20 11
El valor máximo es: 20
Introduzca la base del número a elevar: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at UsingMyMath.main(UsingMyMath.java:18)
```

Les adjunto un *PDF* con las pautas que he tenido que seguir para escribir el código.

[Practica 4 UPV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ov-UidqaY4U3diWWdkSUZSWlk/view?usp=sharing) (El problema se encuentra en el punto 7)

Comment: Cuando ingresas base, que numero ingresas? Con coma (,) o punto (.)?

Comment: @sioesi Para este error no tendría que ver ya que saltaría un `InputMismatchException`

Comment: @sioesi        El problema es que no me deja introducir nada, tan pronto termino de introducir los datos en la primera parte del programa, este me devuelve cual es el número mayor, me pregunta la base del número a elevar y cuando llega ahí salta la excepción. No me deja introducir el double...

Comment: Sospecho que es porque abres dos `Scanner` con el mismo stream (System.in) en un mismo proyecto.

Comment: @Error404      El Scanner que abro en la clase anterior está cerrado para cuando se abre ese Scanner. ¿Me equivoco? EDITO: De hecho se llaman diferente.

Comment: Yo tambien pense lo mismo @Error404  pero los cierra... creo que asi mismo deberia solucionarse

Comment: Ya vi el problema no es que lo abra, sino que lo cierra, lo que ocasiona que la entrada se cierre. quita         tec.close(); y prueba

Comment: @Ajeno Correcto! Ya funciona. Muchísimas gracias a todos, habéis sido muy rápidos y amables :)

Comment: @Ajeno ¿Entonces cuando cierro una entrada queda cerrada para siempre en java?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tu tienes un flujo, puede ser Un archivo, entrada estandar, etc, por lo que al darle close el código dice que si la fuente es Closeable, por seguridad la cierre también.

Comment: @Ajeno Perfecto, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bien visto @Ajeno, no me había dado cuenta de ese detalle. Lo mejor sería que pusieras una respuesta con respecto a porque si haces scanner.close el stream que tengas abierto se cierra. Creo que podría ser bastante interesante para futuros lectores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que cuando utilizas la línea `tec.close()` lo que estás cerrando en realidad es el método de entrada de datos. Esto lo podemos encontrar en la **[documentación de la clase Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)**:

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

lo que viene a decir que cuando una instancia de `Scanner` es cerrada, cerrará su método de entrada de datos si este método implementa la interfaz `Closeable`.

Y, tal y como podemos ver en la documentación de la clase **[`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in)**, este es en realidad un **[`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)**, el cual implementa la interfaz `Closeable`, tal y como se puede observar en su documentación:

> All Implemented Interfaces:
>   Closeable, AutoCloseable

Por lo tanto, al utilizar `System.in` el cual si que implementa la clase `Closeable` y utilizar `Scanner.close`, el método de entrada (`System.in`) se cierra y es por eso que para el segundo `Scanner` no podemos leer los datos.

Para resolver tu error simplemente quita la línea `tec.close()`.

Answer (score 2):

Borre la linea 19 de la clase MyMath.(tec.close();) Se refiere al cierre de tu objeto Scanner. 
Sólo se puede cerrar una vez System.in. Si queres volver a utilizar, el mismo, crea una variable final somo por ejemplo:

```
static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Hola @josego, no es necesario que copies de nuevo todo el código para referirte a una línea en concreto. Podrías directamente copiar la línea que has eliminado del código. Por otro lado, sería muy interesante que añadieras una explicación de porque quitando esa línea el error ya no existe.

Comment: @Error404 ya esta explicado y borre todo el código. Gracias

Comment: Gracias @josego :)

Comment: @leandroalbero por nada. Estamos para ayudar en lo que podemos